# facing error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'StepDefinitions & Hooks'

Tags: visual-studio-code, protractor, cucumber

facing error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'StepDefinitions & Hooks'. 
when I am trying to run tsc -w

tried all the solution which I know but nothing is working out.

Feature file:

```
Feature: Login creation for Amazon AWS

    Scenario: Successful creation of Login
        Given User navigate to Home Page
        When User enter email and other details
        Then Login is created sucessfully
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "package",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^12.7.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js -p default"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/cucumber": "^4.0.7",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "cucumber": "^5.1.0",
    "cucumber-pretty": "^1.5.2",
    "cucumber-tsflow": "^3.2.0",
    "exceljs": "^2.0.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1"
  },
  "author": "Bharani",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Step Definition file:

```
import { Given, When, Then } from "cucumber"


Given("User navigate to Home Page", function(){


       console.log("hafd");
});
When("User enter email and other details",function(){

  console.log("dfhagsdf");

});
Then("Login is created sucessfully",function(){

  console.log("dhfhd");
});
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "package",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^12.7.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js -p default"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/cucumber": "^4.0.7",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "cucumber": "^5.1.0",
    "cucumber-pretty": "^1.5.2",
    "cucumber-tsflow": "^3.2.0",
    "exceljs": "^2.0.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1"
  },
  "author": "Bharani",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**Error in console:**

> '''[16:44:58] Starting compilation in watch mode...
>
> POM_TS_CUCUMBER/Featurefile/stepdefinition/Steps.ts:3:32 - error
>   TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'StepDefinitions &
>   Hooks'.
>
> 3 defineSupportCode(({Given,When,then}) =>{
>                                    ~~~~
>
> [16:45:04] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes. '''

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Please find below for error.   [16:44:58] Starting compilation in watch mode...

POM_TS_CUCUMBER/Featurefile/stepdefinition/Steps.ts:3:32 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'StepDefinitions & Hooks'.

3 defineSupportCode(({Given,When,then}) =>{
                                 ~~~~

[16:45:04] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.

Comment: Please add this to your question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have written Then in feature file which is not from the cucumber library. Try writing then statement again from cucumber library and try again.

Comment: how can i differentiate between Cucumber library Then and other Then in cucumber.Can you share the details.Because i am quite new to protractor